# Design Issues with Inheritance Implementation

Tags: oop, inheritance, architecture

Initial Situation:- I had 20 different classes, one each containing code to provide feed to each downstream system, so 20 classes for 20 systems. No I hire a architect to simplify my code.

Architect suggested applying OOP principles that we should use inheritance and move common functionality to base class and use is a relationship with 20 classes.

Problem:- This increased my testability efforts, earlier we had separate code for each downstream so need to regress with one system only but now for any change in base class, we need to test with 20 systems, so applying OOP's created more problems.

What should be the design to solve this problem?

Comment: with those much informations about the classes, the systems, the code, the architecture, the technology, the languages, how can't we be super uper duper helpful?

Comment: btw, inheriting from an abstract class most of the times is not a good idea, it's easy to violate the SOLID principles with it... if you have common code, create a `Service` class that does exactly that, so that you can test that functionality isolated to the entire system

Comment: I'm not sure I see how use of a base-class suddenly changes the test regime *that* much.  The structure changes but you still have 20 classes (plus the base class).

Comment: 'What should be the design to solve this problem?'  For that we'll need more information about the situation, and what you're trying to achieve, rather than criticism of what the architect said you should do.  For example what's a "feed", what drives the need for 20 different classes, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can try to use composition instead of inheritance. This might result in a more stable downstream-specific object which then doesn't need to be tested when common things change. Depending on your exact case this may or may not help, but is a sensible alternative at least.

Obviously we don't know your exact circumstances. *In general* inheritance is really problematic and should be avoided if possible.

A bit more specifically, inheriting from a baseclass to share code (I'm assuming this is your case, I don't know for sure) is also not a good practice. So strike two for inheritance.

*Composition* involves creating a useful abstraction for the common things. Basically a standalone object or objects that do something useful, but not downstream specific. Then *using* those objects in the downstream-specific objects, instead of inheriting any of it.